Probability That the Mean of a Random Subset Exceeds the Overall Mean
Problem Statement:
Suppose there are $n$ given non-negative real numbers $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ with arithmetic mean
$$
\overline{x} = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i.
$$
From these $n$ numbers, we randomly select $k$ numbers without replacement, where $1 \leq k \leq n$, and each subset of size $k$ is equally likely to be chosen. Let $\overline{x}_k$ denote the arithmetic mean of the selected numbers:
$$
\overline{x}_k = \dfrac{1}{k} \sum_{i \in S} x_i,
$$
where $S$ is the randomly selected subset of indices of size $k$.
Question:
Consider the specific case where $k = \dfrac{n}{4}$ (assuming $n$ is divisible by 4). Prove that
$$
P\left( \overline{x}_k \geq \overline{x} \right) \geq \dfrac{1}{4},
$$
or provide a counterexample.

My Worst-Case Analysis and Current Thoughts:
In the worst-case scenario, all the total sum is concentrated in a single number. Specifically, suppose all $x_i = 0$ except for one number $x_{\text{max}}$, which equals the total sum:
$$
x_{\text{max}} = n \overline{x}.
$$
In this case:

The total sum is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x_{\text{max}} = n \overline{x}$.

When selecting $k = \dfrac{n}{4}$ numbers, the probability of selecting $x_{\text{max}}$ is $\dfrac{k}{n} = \dfrac{1}{4}$.

If $x_{\text{max}}$ is selected, then the mean of the selected numbers is:
$$
  \overline{x}_k = \dfrac{x_{\text{max}}}{k} = \dfrac{n \overline{x}}{n/4} = 4 \overline{x},
  $$
which is greater than $\overline{x}$.

If $x_{\text{max}}$ is not selected, then $\overline{x}_k = 0$, which is less than $\overline{x}$.


Therefore, in this worst-case scenario:
$$
P\left( \overline{x}_k \geq \overline{x} \right) = \dfrac{1}{4}.
$$
This represents the minimal possible probability for the event $\overline{x}_k \geq \overline{x}$.
In general cases, where the non-zero values of $x_i$ are distributed among multiple elements, the probability $P\left( \overline{x}_k \geq \overline{x} \right)$ should be higher because:

Each non-zero $x_i$ has a chance of being included in the sample.
The more non-zero $x_i$ there are, the greater the likelihood that the sum of the selected numbers meets or exceeds $k \overline{x}$.

I believe that the inequality
$$
P\left( \overline{x}_k \geq \overline{x} \right) \geq \dfrac{k}{n}
$$
holds in general for any $k$ (with $1 \leq k \leq n$), since each individual number has a selection probability of $\dfrac{k}{n}$, and the expected value of $\overline{x}_k$ is $\overline{x}$:
$$
E\left[ \overline{x}_k \right] = \overline{x}.
$$
However, I have not been able to provide a rigorous proof of this inequality. I am seeking either a formal proof or a counterexample that disproves it.
Any insights, proofs, or counterexamples would be greatly appreciated.

A New Idea:
Treat the random selection of $ k = \frac{n}{4} $ elements as taking the first $ k $ elements after randomly permuting the $ n $ non-negative numbers. By partitioning the permuted sequence into four parts of size $ \frac{n}{4} $, the total sum remains $ n \overline{x} $. It's impossible for all four parts to have sums less than $ \frac{n}{4} \overline{x} $, so at least one part must have a sum greater than or equal to $ \frac{n}{4} \overline{x} $. Due to symmetry, each part is equally likely to be that part, so the probability that the first part (our random subset) has a sum at least $ \frac{n}{4} \overline{x} $ is at least $ \frac{1}{4} $. This suggests that the probability $ P\left( \overline{x}_{k} \geq \overline{x} \right) \geq \frac{1}{4} $.
I'm not sure if this forms a rigorous proof, but it seems like a promising approach to establish the inequality.

Question Revision:
I appreciate everyone's answers and comments. All the discussions are very insightful. Based on the answer by @quasi, the conclusion has been proven for the case where $k|n$. However, in other cases, there are many counterexamples provided by @Litho, @Zoe Allen, and @Sangchul Lee. So that the conclusion does not hold. Is it possible to establish a weaker lower bound, such as
$$ P\left( \overline{x}_k \geq \overline{x} \right) > \frac{1}{2}\min\left\{\dfrac{k}{n},1-\dfrac{k}{n}\right\} \;\; ?$$
Or how should the conclusion be revised?

Thank you for your reminder, I have edited the question.

Your New Idea is a good one.  To make it sound more rigorous you can talk about separating the permutations into equivalence classes based on the four groups.  This makes it clearer that you really have at least a one out of four selection.

A simpler way to see it is to make the random selection in two stages: (i) partition uniformly randomly into four equal sets (ii) choose one of these uniformly at random. Now the result follows since irrespective of the outcome of (i), (ii) gives at least a $1/4$ chance of giving what you want.

I'll resolve the special case where $k{\,\mid\,}n$.

Thus let $n,k$ be positive integers such that $k{\,\mid\,}n$.

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $y_1,...,y_n$ be a random reordering of $x_1,...,x_n$.

Let $p$ be given by
$$
p=\mathbb{P}\left(
\frac{y_1+\cdots +y_k}{k}
\ge
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{n}
\right)
$$
Claim:$\;p\ge{\large{\frac{k}{n}}}$.

Proof:

Let $m={\large{\frac{n}{k}}}$.

For $i\in\{1,...,m\}$ let
$$
s_i
=
\sum_{j=1}^k y_{j+(i-1)k}
$$
and let $p_i=\mathbb{P}(A_i)$ where $A_i$ is the event that
$$
\frac{s_i}{k}
\ge
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{n}
$$
Identically we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m s_i=x_1+\cdots +x_n
$$
hence, since ${\large{\frac{m}{n}}}={\large{\frac1{k}}}$, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{s_i}{k}
=
m\left(
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{n}
\right)
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{s_i}{k}
\ge
\frac{x_1+\cdots +x_n}{n}
$$
for at least one $i$.

Thus the event $A_i$ occurs for at least one $i$, hence
$$
\mathbb{P}
\left(
\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i
\right)
=
1
$$
Now by definition we have $p_1=p$, and by symmetry we have $p_i=p$ for all $i$, hence
\begin{align*}
p
&=
\frac1{m}
\sum_{i=1}^m p_i
=
\frac1{m}
\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{P}(A_i)
\ge
\frac1{m}
\mathbb{P}
\left(
\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i
\right)
=
\frac1{m}
=
\frac{k}{n}
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

Thank you very much for your answer. For the non-divisible case, my first instinct is to use induction, but I have not yet found a workable approach.

The statement about general $k$ is not true: take $n=3$, $k=2$, $x_1=x_2=1$, $x_3=0$. Then the probability is $\frac 1 3$.

Building on Litho's answer, this is not true in general. Consider the case where $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}=1$ and $x_n=0$. $\bar{x}=\frac{n-1}n$ and $\bar{x}_k \ge \bar{x}$ iff $x_n$ is not included in the $k$ subset. So with probability $1-\frac{k}{n}$. This is a counterexample for $k > \frac{n}{2}$.
We can also reflect this distribution, taking $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}=0$ and $x_n=1$ and find $P(\bar{x}_k \ge \bar{x}) = \frac{k}{n}$.
I wonder if the correct version of the statement would be:
$$P(\bar{x}_k \ge \bar{x}) \ge \min \{ \frac{k}{n}, 1-\frac{k}{n} \}$$

On your final line, no.  Take $n=5$, $k=3$, and numbers $1,1,0,0,0$  (adapting a Litho comment to another answer, and Sangchul Lee's answer).  So $\frac kn = 0.6$ and $\bar x= 0.4$ but $P(\bar x_k \ge \bar x) = 0.3$ since you need both $1$s and one of the three $0$s.

An extensive numerical experiment suggests that:

Conjecture. $\mathbb{P}(\bar{x}_k \geq \bar{x}) \geq \min\{\frac{k}{n}, 1-\frac{k}{n}, \frac{1}{4}\}$.

For example, the figure below is the plot of the function
$$ k \mapsto \min_{(x_i) \in \{0, 1\}^n} \mathbb{P}(\bar{x}_k \geq \bar{x}), $$
the minimum of all values of $\mathbb{P}(\bar{x}_k \geq \bar{x})$ where $x_i$'s are taken from $\{0, 1\}$, when $n = 101$:


what possibilities have you searched?

@ZoeAllen, Besides the case where $x_i$'s take only one of the two possible values (which we can assume $0$ and $1$ for an obvious reason), I also tested randomly generated $x_i$'s using either uniform or gaussian distributions, and it seems that the minimum is achieved when $x_i$'s are "extreme", essentially reducing to the aforementioned case. (This is still an empirical observation, though.) When $x_i\in{0,1}$, the probability can be computed analytically using hypergeometric distribution. This is what I used to produce the figure above.

I am getting the same number 0.252 when k=50 when the number of 1's in x is 99.

This is not a complete answer but it is too long to post as a comment. Below are some ideas/observations that did not lead to a solution but might be useful. We call a subset $S$ of $[n] := \{1,2,\dots, n\}$ good if
$$\frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{i\in S}x_i \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
and bad otherwise. Let $G_k$ be the number of good subsets of $[n]$ of size exactly $k$ and $B_k$ the number of bad subsets of $[n]$ of size exactly $k$. It is easy to see that if $S$ is a good subset of size $k$ then $S^c = [n] \setminus S$ is a bad subset of size $n-k$ and vice-versa. This proves that $G_k = B_{n-k}$ for all $k\in [n]$. Furthermore, we have
$$G_k + B_k = G_k + G_{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}\quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k=1}^nG_k=2^{n-1}-1$$
Finally, we can see that $G_1 \geq 1$ since the singleton that contains the maximum among the $x_i$'s is a good subset. Now we want to prove that
$$G_k \geq \frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}$$
or equivalently that
$$G_{n-k} \leq \frac{n-k}{k}G_k$$
This is not true for general $k$ (as shown by @Litho) but it must hold for $k\mid n$. Finding all the values $k$ for which the above holds is an interesting problem.

This is not true either. Take $n=5$, $k=2$, and numbers 1,1,1,0,0.

@Litho You're right. I'm modifying the answer.

Your "new idea" is indeed apt.
Assume we have $n = k \, t$ elements, so we have $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$.
Let's group those subsets in $\frac1t\binom{n}{k}$ classes, each class having $t$ subsets, such that the subsets in each class have no elements in common, and hence their union cover the $n$ elements. This is always possible (though the fact is not self evident, nor trivial to prove), see here. Let $j=1,2 \cdots \frac1t\binom{n}{k}$ index this classes.
Because each class comprises the full set, the average inside each class is the same as the global average: $\overline{x} $.
Because the subsets inside a class are a partition of the full set, then at least one of them has average greater or equal than the full set.
Then, then letting $E$ be the event of interest: $$P(E) = \sum_j P(E|j) P(j) \ge \sum_j \frac{1}{t} P(j)= \frac{1}{t}$$
